# Send Ajax Response Data to another aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

NET WEB API and I have searched form who get data in JSON format, actually the response data I show it in the same page.

I want to to send this data to another page with ajax, if it is possible, and show the results there. 
This is the AJAX Code:

```
function AJAX_search_Profile(data) {
    //alert('Ajax1');
    if (!false)
        //alert('Ajax2');
        ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../api/Controllers/Manage_Search/search_Profile_by_Many_criterion",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data
        });
    ajaxRequest.done(function (responseData, textStatus) {
        AJAX_CallBack_search_Profile_by_Name(responseData, textStatus);
    });
}

//Callback method 
function AJAX_CallBack_search_Profile_by_Name(responseData, textStatus) {
    if (textStatus == 'success') {
        if (responseData != null) {
            if (responseData.Key) {
                //  alert(responseData.Value);
                var JsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(responseData.Value);

            fill_in_Data(JsonData.docs);
            //window.location.replace("./Home/Members");
            // with this methode i print search result in the same 
            //page ,what i would is to redirect to another page and send this data with it
            //in ajax
        } else {
            alert(responseData.Value);
        }
    }
} else {
    alert(responseData.Value);
}
```

}

Comment: Why not pass the data in a querystring? I assume the data is in a database or some sort of data store.

Comment: Yes good idea thank's